# WebSocket needs browser refresh to update list

Tags: javascript, express, sockets, websocket, web-development-server

My project works as intended except that I have to refresh the browser every time my keyword list sends something to it to display. I assume it's my inexperience with Expressjs and not creating the route correctly within my websocket? Any help would be appreciated.

**Browser**

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000");

socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) { 
  console.log('Connected to WS server')
  socket.send('Hello Server!'); 
}); 

socket.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
  const keywordsList = JSON.parse(e.data);
  console.log("Received: '" + e.data + "'");
  document.getElementById("keywordsList").innerHTML = e.data;
}); 

socket.onclose = function(code, reason) {
  console.log(code, reason, 'disconnected');
}

socket.onerror = error => {
  console.error('failed to connect', error);
};
```

**Server**

```
const ws = require('ws');
const express = require('express');
const keywordsList = require('./app');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const wsServer = new ws.Server({ noServer: true });
wsServer.on('connection', function connection(socket) {
  socket.send(JSON.stringify(keywordsList));
  socket.on('message', message => console.log(message));
});

// `server` is a vanilla Node.js HTTP server, so use
// the same ws upgrade process described here:
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#multiple-servers-sharing-a-single-https-server
const server = app.listen(3000);
server.on('upgrade', (request, socket, head) => {
  wsServer.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, socket => {
    wsServer.emit('connection', socket, request);
  });
});
```

Comment: The post doesn't contain code to allow the server to be notified when the keyword list has been updated, so that it can push the changes. At the moment it (the server) only sends the list when a browser connects or reconnects after page reload. How is the keyword list updated and have you tried to notify the server of the update?

Comment: Thank you for the response.

So my understanding of WebSockets just pushing that information regardless of other circumstance is wrong then? If I write a function that evaluates the keywordList, it should send every time it is updated? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of the webSocket in the first place if I had an ajax version of this working?

Comment: WebSockets is a transport protocol - it doesn't push information automatically, say when a file system file is updated. To push information the server needs to send information using [WebSocket.send()](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/HEAD/doc/ws.md#websocketsenddata-options-callback) after determining or being notified that keywords have been updated.

Comment: I understand that now but I am still at a loss for my original problem which is how to send and/or stream array data that is being continually updated to a client. I made an express and ajax solution a long time ago but I really thought this was something websockets should just do? And somehow there isn't a single example online of this which makes me think I am doing something very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In answer to "**How to Send and/or Stream array data that is being continually updated to a client**" as arrived at in comment.*

A possible solution using WebSockets may be to

1. Create an interface on the server for array updates (if you haven't already) that isolates the array object from arbitrary outside modification and supports a callback when updates are made.
2. Determine the latency allowed for multiple updates to occur without being pushed. The latency should allow reasonable time for previous network traffic to complete without overloading bandwidth unnecessarily.
3. When an array update occurs, start a timer *if not already running* for the latency period .
4. On timer expiry `JSON.stringify` the array (to take a snapshot), clear the timer running status, and message the client with the JSON text.

A slightly more complicated method to avoid delaying all push operations would be to immediately push single updates *unless they occur within a guard period after the most recent push operation.* A timer could then push modifications made during the guard period at the end of the guard period.

---

#### Broadcasting

The WebSockets API does not directly support broadcasting the same data to multiple clients. Refer to [Server Broadcast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#server-broadcast) in `ws` documentation for an example of sending data to all connected clients using a `forEach` loop.

---

**Client side listener**

In the client-side message listener

```
document.getElementById("keywordsList").innerHTML = e.data;
```

would be better as

```
document.getElementById("keywordsList").textContent = keywordList;
```

to both present keywords after decoding from JSON and prevent them ever being treated as HTML.

Comment: This is a fantastic comment and sums up essentially all that I have learned and then some so far. Thank you. It's been really frustrating learning that WebSockets don't really transmit data from arrays in real time like I thought they would in my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out what I wanted to accomplish. It sounds straight forward after I learned enough and thought about how to structure the back end of my project.

If you have two websockets running and one needs information from the other, you cannot run them side by side. You need to have one encapsulate the other and then call the websocket INSIDE of the other websocket. This can easily cause problems down the road for other projects since now you have one websocket that won't fire until the other is run but for my project it makes perfect sense since it is locally run and needs all the parts working 100 percent in order to be effective. It took me a long time to understand how to structure the code as such.